# terraform lookup default value must have the same type as the map elements

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Just trying to create IAM users with optional tags:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "root" {
  for_each = var.iam_users_root
  name     = each.key
  tags     = lookup(each.value, "tags", {})
}
```

Variable:

```
variable "iam_users_root" {
  type        = map(any)
  default     = {}
}
```

*tfvars*:

```
iam_users_root = {
  "usr1": {},
  "usr2": {"tags": {"key": "value"}},
}
```

However `terraform` throws an error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on iam_users.tf line 4, in resource "aws_iam_user" "root":
   4:   tags     = lookup(each.value, "tags", {})

Invalid value for "default" parameter: the default value must have the same
type as the map elements.
```

Interestingly if all the users have no tags, then `terraform` does not complain:

```
iam_users_root = {
  "usr1": {},
  "usr2": {},
}
```

Any ideas?

BTW:

```
> terraform --version
Terraform v0.14.2
```

Comment: I don't get an error with this, but I had to guess about the way you've defined the variable `iam_users_root`. Maybe you could post a reproducible example?

Comment: @MarkM See the edit, now there's all the data needed to reproduce.

Comment: Looks like it's probably a [bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26265), at least there's a similar open issue in GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled into this same problem today, and after some quick search I found that the best (and actually my way out of this) was to be specific on my variable types instead of letting Terraform trying to figure it out (and fail in the process). Let me explain myself:

It is quite convenient to use `map(any)` as your variable type, it leads to situations where Terraform is not able to infer those types.

For us humans both `"usr1": {}` and `"usr2": {"tags": {"key": "value"}}` perfectly fit in the `map(any)` category, as it makes sense that any can be a map, empty or not. For Terraform however, it would look like this:

```
"usr1": {} = map
"usr2": {"tags": {"key": "value"}} = map(object({key: string}))
```

Causing Terraform to send you that error message. It seems to me that while it is "possible" to have the `any` flexibility to a certain extent, it is desired and expected from you to be as specific on the types you're going to use. If you wish to read a bit further on the subject, you can check both the [bug link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26265) in previous responses as well as [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27509). Both were attended by the same guy, which makes it consistent on the resolution of being type specific.